# Older induction motor needs spin to start it

Tags: capacitor, induction-motor

Tl:DR  Motor requires hand spin to start.  No starter switch.

**EDIT Further information:**

So I tried removing the capacitor completely.  Started it.

Starts very slowly, with much grumbling.  Give it a small spin by hand, and it takes off now making normal motor sounds.

Query:  There are three leads to the capacitor:  2 black and 1 red.

Alas, when I first unwired the capacitor I didn't note the colors.  I'm *guessing* that the two black connect to one terminal, the single red to the other.

**/Edit**

Motor is very old, from a Rockwell table saw, befroe they sold out to Delta.  Motor has a capacitor but no start switch, so I think it's a PSC type.

My limited understanding of PSC motors is that they have two windings, but both contribute to the run time field full time.

Now the motor doesn't start on it's own, but will run normally if I spin it.

I've checked the capacitor, and it still checks within 10% of it's rated capacity of, I think the tech said, 450 mmF

EDIT:  Said *with* instead of *within*

I'm confused as to how to fix this.  My initial thinking is that I'm hooped.  Motors this size (1.5 hp) are not repaired anymore, but the motor has a non standard mount so replacing it will be a pain.

My suspicion is that the starter winding has failed.

I'm reaching out here to see if there is something I've overlooked.

Comment: If the capacitor only has 10% of its rated capacity, that's your problem right there. Replace that capacitor.

Comment: Sherwood, I had to replace capacitors in a table saw motor in order to get it running correctly, as well. They do wear out. On some, there's also what's called a 'start capacitor' and a separate 'run capacitor' -- but there's a separate switch involved for motors that include the start capacitor. Sounds like yours just has the run capacitor. 450 uF seems a little high to me, though, for a 1.5 HP motor. Like about 10X too high. So the 10% reading you got is making me wonder. But I don't know about the auxillary winding, either. So... Maybe my memory is wrong.

Comment: If you decide to buy a replacement capacitor, make sure the AC voltage rating is at least what's listed on the capacitor you have (though I'm not trusting it much, now.) Also, you may want to get several values -- perhaps 30 uF, 150 uF, and that 450 uF. (I'm saying this only because I'm still struck by the high nameplate value and low measured value and wondering if this capacitor had been previously replaced and perhaps incorrectly, which worked for a while but isn't now.)

Comment: It may be that the large value was there to give it a boost in starting up, but then it would likely be the wrong value while running. You could also consider adding a centrifugal switch to the motor, along with a start capacitor to give it a boost only when starting, leaving the run capacitor alone during operation for better performance. Anyway, best wishes!

Comment: measuring the capacitance can be inconclusive as I've had those capacitors measure just fine in terms of capacitance but fail to work adequately. A simple test is to measure the AC voltage across the capacitor. I would expect a value of a few 10's of volts at a maximum. Or just replace the capacitor as it is an item that wears out.

Comment: Measure the resistance of the winding attached to the capacitor. In my experience the resistance will be somewhat larger than the primary winding.

Comment: @Kartman Thanks.  I will try this, as it is the cheapest way forward at this point.